# Generating Javascript Code via a JSON Request

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find a tool to use that can generate JavaScript code from a JSON request. The use case is to allow users to fill in a web interface form field with different types of data. When the form is completed and sent to the backend, the backend would process the received data and output a JS file for users to download.

Comment: A very interesting question, although I am afraid that you will end up coding it yourself